# How can I print a list and an int next to each other

Tags: python-3.8

Im trying to print the 'word results' and the 'number results' next to each other without spaces but unfortunately everything that I've tried hasn't worked and it will only print it out vertically.

```
import random

user_Input = input('Strong Or Weak?: ')
wrds = ['p', 'e', 'T', 'U', 'S', 'C', 'v', 'Q', 't', 'V', 'I', 'R', 'K', 'A', 'G', 'l', 'r', 'u', 'b', 'P', 'p', 'n', 'H', 'i', 'R', 'I', 'w', 'K', 'v', 'F', 'J', 'y', 'B', 'h', 'o', 'a', 'G', 'X', 'z']
rndm_num = random.randint(9999,99999)
rndm_wrds = random.sample(wrds , k = 8 )
result_wrds= rndm_wrds
result_num = rndm_num

if user_Input == 'Strong' or 'strong':
print(*result_wrds, sep ='') , print(result_num)
```

Comment: How does you expected output looks like?

Comment: it prints it out vertically

Comment: Do I understand it correct that the expected output would be: `CunvvzpI52080` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: In this case, please check out my answer. It should print out CunvvzpI52080. If it was helpful, I would appreciate if you could upvote it. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the results in the same line, you can use the same print() satetment.

```
if user_Input == 'Strong' or 'strong':
    print(*result_wrds, result_num, sep ='')

# CunvvzpI52080
```